# Python string and array not working properly

Tags: python, arrays, django, list, python-3.x

From conditionId input field i am getting comma separated string eg 'Test1','Test2','Test3' below is the code for that i want to split that string and access individual value using for loop

```
ConditionId =str(request.POST.getlist("ConditionId"))
ConditionIdArray = [n for n in ConditionId[1:-1].split(',')]

for i in range(0,len(ConditionIdArray)):
    print(ConditionIdArray[i])
```

In print statement it giving me output as

```
'Test1'
'Test2'
'Test3'
```

but i want output as

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

Because when i am storing data in database it stored as **'Test1' not as normal Test1**

Answer (score 4):

[`POST.getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) will return a list of strings. Don't convert it string and split, just iterate it (no need to use `range` and indexing):

```
condition_ids = request.POST.getlist("ConditionId")

for condition_id in condition_ids:
    print(condition_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

A little explanatory addition to @falsetru's answer. The `str()` of a `list` uses `repr()` for displaying its elements, thus for `[x, y, z]` it is:

```
[repr(x), repr(y), repr(z)]
```

and not, as one might expect

```
[str(x), str(y), str(z)]
```

And for strings, that makes a difference:

```
> s = 'Test1'
> print(str(s))
Test1

> print(repr(s))
'Test1'  # so, splitting the str(list) on commas leaves the quotes
```